# Sagemaker Neo Compilation witn Dynamic Input Data Size

Tags: amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to compile a `PyTorch` model to a raspberry pie 3. The model that I am using does not have any limitation in regards to the width and the height. Sagemaker Neo takes in a `Data input configuration` parameter which looks like it needs to be fixed from the documentation and the examples.

```
Data Input Configuration:  
Amazon SageMaker needs to know the what the shape of the data matrix is
{"data": [1, 3, 224, 224]}
```

The above example can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-job-compilation-console.html).

I need something like the following:

```
Data Input Configuration:  
Amazon SageMaker needs to know the what the shape of the data matrix is
{"data": [1, 3, *, *]}
```

entering the above yields the following error message:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 17 of the JSON data
```

and fixing the height and the width yields the following message:

```
ClientError: InputConfiguration: Invalid PyTorch model or input-shape mismatch. Make sure that inputs are lexically ordered and of the correct dimensionality.
```

Is there anyway to specify that I want 1 images, with 3 channels, and variable height and width?